# How to get parent elements in the dojo custom popup

Tags: jsp, dojo

Need to change a label in the parent window once I click on the submit button in the dojo template based custom popup.

```
creating widget from parent.
     new com.test.widget.testWidget({panel: this});
<label id="a">test</label>
--------------------------------

in the custom widget 

show:function(){
        // need to change the value of the parent label "a"
    },
```

I'm sure that I explained correctly ... Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data-dojo-attach-point to the label in parent widget like

```
<label id="a" data-dojo-attach-point="labelA">test</label>
```

then in the show function

```
show: function(){
    this.panel.labelA.innerHTML = "hello world"
}
```